# Remove an imprinted logo from an electric device

Tags: cleaning, plastics, paint

The Kindle Paperwhite gen. 2 has one annoying flaw: A shiny silver logo directly under the screen (see [here](http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/18/923867-amazon-kindle.jpg)). I can mask it with a piece of black electrician's tape, but I'd like to remove it altogether. As far as you can tell:

1. By what process was this imprint made?
2. What is the best way to remove it without harming the device? (heat? solvent? careful abrasion?)

Note that while this is a device-specific question, the same question applies to a variety of other gadgets and electronic devices that have visually-intrusive front facing logos.

Comment: a case maybe? I personally don't like altering the integrity of my devices.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe spray paint black or use nail polish to black it. If it's sticking out, maybe some fine sand paper, but that will easily make scratches on your device

Comment: Make a mold first, or use tape to make a neat rectangle shape and color it black

Answer (score 2):

The logo appears to be printed to the underside of the bezel. You would need to remove the outer layer of the screen and replace the coating with something all black. An RC hobby shop would have replacement material to re-skin the screen.

Removal of existing glue is best done with hot water followed by isopropyl alcohol.

Note; this will most definitely void any warranty.